# Trying to implement basic subtraction function between two rows of dataframe based on the months of datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the average monthly gap between stock closing and opening prices which are in dataframe.
The basic function looks like this

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    #difference between today's opening price minus yesterday's closing price
    gap+=(df['Open'][i]-df['Close'][i-1])
```

But I want to find this `avg_gap` for every month in my dataframe. And store the `avg_gaps` in a list.
Dataframe has each days opening, highest, lowest and closing price with the associated date (in datetime format)
Looks like this

```
Date        Open    High    Low      Close
2019-01-01  10881.7 10923.6 10807.1 10910.1
2019-01-02  10868.8 10895.3 10735.0 10792.5
2019-01-03  10796.8 10814.0 10661.2 10672.2
2019-01-04  10699.7 10741.0 10628.6 10727.3
2019-01-07  10804.8 10835.9 10750.1 10771.8
2019-01-08  10786.2 10818.4 10733.2 10802.1
```

Like this the dataframe has data for 1.5 years

This is what I have tried

```
list=[]
gap=0
count=0

for i in range(1,len(df)):   
    if(df['Date'][i].month==df['Date'][i-1].month):
        count+=1
        gap+=(df['Open'][i]-df['Close'][i-1])
    if(df['Date'][i].month<df['Date'][i-1].month):
        avg_gap=gap/count
        list.append(avg_gap)
        count=0
        gap=0
```

This isn't giving me the correct answer.

I want 12 `avg_gap` for every month of the year to be appened in the list.

`avg_gaps` are calculated by (total gap in that month)/(total no of days in that month)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create a month column in your `DataFrame` to group by. Then, write a function which calculates the average gap.

#### Gap Calculation

You are adding up lots of differences as follows:

```
 df['Open'][1]-df['Close'][0]
+df['Open'][2]-df['Close'][1]
+df['Open'][3]-df['Close'][2]
+...
```

However, we could group this a different way as follows:

```
 (df['Open'][1]+df['Open'][2]+df['Open'][3]+...)
-(df['Close'][0]+df['Close'][1]+df['Close'][2]+...)
```

So a simpler way to perform your calculation is just as

`df['Open'].iloc[1:].sum()-df['Close'].iloc[:-1].sum()`

#### Code

```
def average_gap(month_df):
    openings = month_df['Open'].iloc[1:].sum()
    closings = month_df['Close'].iloc[:-1].sum()
    number = month_df.shape[0]-1
    
    return (openings-closings)/number

df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
gap_by_month = df.groupby('month').apply(average_gap)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much.